# Issue with FileManager.moveItem

Tags: swift, macos

I have a method that looks at a directory (at a URL) that contains a bunch of jpg files whose filenames end in various suffixes ("_JpgFromRaw", "_ThumbnailImage", "_PreviewImage", etc.)

The jpg files are to be separated into subfolders by their suffixes (if a subfolder of that name doesn't exist then one is created.)

I'm successfully creating the subfolders but when I try to move the files to their respective folders the moveItem throws the error that "a file with that name already exists."
So none of the files get moved.

Can someone please help me identify the problem with the method as I have written it?

Thank you for any advice.

```
func separateExtractedJPGsInDirectoryAtURL(url:URL) {
    do {
    let contents = try fm.contentsOfDirectory(at: url, includingPropertiesForKeys: [], options: [.skipsHiddenFiles])
       // var dest : URL!
        for file in contents {
            let fileNameComponents : [String] = file.lastPathComponent.components(separatedBy: "_")
            let jpgTypeWithExtension : [String] = fileNameComponents[fileNameComponents.count - 1].components(separatedBy: ".")
            let jpgType : String = jpgTypeWithExtension[0]
            let dest = url.appendingPathComponent(jpgType)
           
            do {
            try fm.createDirectory(at: url.appendingPathComponent(jpgType), withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil)
            
            } catch {
                do {
                try fm.moveItem(at: file, to: dest)
                } catch {print("error: \(error)")}
            }
        }
    } catch {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a full URL for a destination, but you are trying to move file to a directory(???)

```swift
do {
    try fm.createDirectory(at: dest, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil)
} catch {
    do {
        try fm.moveItem(at: file, to: dest.appendingPathComponent(file.lastPathComponent))
    } catch {print("error: \(error)")}
}
```

And it's likely you would need to check the directory existence before trying to create it, as it might already exist

```swift
func fileExists(atPath path: String) -> Bool
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
I was misunderstanding how .moveTo should work. I thought I should provide the URL of a destination directory rather than the complete URL.